# How do i put video in listview builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to add a video player to my Listview.builder(child:???).Every video must have different links how can i do that?

### ListviewBuilder

```
>  buildSectionTitle(context, 'Videos'),
        buildContainer(
          ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 5,
                        horizontal: 10,
                      ),
                      child: ???,
                ),

          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Include the code in your question. Not pictures of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st step**: [Add video player plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

**2nd step**: create a new widget containing vieo(for each element of your `ListView`

```
class VideoItem extends StatefulWidget {
final string url;

VideoItem(this.url);
    @override
      _VideoItemState createState() => VideoItem();
    }

class _VideoItemState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ?Stack(childre:[ AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),),
Center(child;:GestureDetector(onTap:_playPause,
child:Icon(Icons.play_circle))

]
                    )
                  : Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
_playPause(){
if(_controller.isPlaying){
_controller.pause();
}else{
_controller.play();
}
}
```

**Then** : Use it in `ListView`

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: listOfVideoUrl.length, //Notice this
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => VideoItem(listOfVideoUrl[index]))
```

**NOTE**: This is not the best way to achieve this . consider using images in `ListView`then open player page after users click

Comment: How can i contact to you? i need to ask one minor question.